# Gruntfile error, what is wrong?

Tags: javascript, command-line, npm, gruntjs

Im getting this error when trying to execute grunt

```
     $ grunt
Loading "Gruntfile.js" tasks...ERROR
>> SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
Warning: Task "default" not found. Use --force to continue.
```

Aborted due to warnings.

My gruntfile is as follows:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  grunt.initConfig({
    cssmin: {
      target: {
        files: {[
          expand: true,
          cwd: '/css',
          src: [ '*.css', '!*min.css.' ],
          ext: '.min.css'
        ]}
      }
    }
    watch: {
      sass: {
        files: ['sass/*.sass'],
        tasks: ['sass'],
      },
    },
  });
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-cssmin');
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['watch']);
};
```

All of my dependencies are properly installed and inside the package.json. I've stripped everything down to just this test file, I would normally have more tasks. I've rewritten it in coffeescript to no avail. Passing any value for `grunt.registerTask()` throws and error for the named value, rather than default.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had a couple of syntax errors. One was that you were missing a comma before the "watch" and the other one was the "files" array in the "cssmin" task.

This should work:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  grunt.initConfig({
    cssmin: {
      target: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '/css',
          src: [ '*.css', '!*min.css.' ],
          ext: '.min.css'
        }]
      }
    },
    watch: {
      sass: {
        files: ['sass/*.sass'],
        tasks: ['sass'],
      },
    },
  });
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-cssmin');
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['watch']);
};
```